# Getting Raster Pixel Values within Specified distance of Vector Layer

Tags: qgis, raster, vector

I have a raster layer with an overlaid vector layer as shown below. I would like to get all of the raster values within a specified distance of the vector lines.

Is there a method for doing this in QGIS or is this a problem that would be better solved through scripting?

[image: Raster with vector overlaid]

Comment: What have you tried so far? What does "get" mean to you in this usecase? What further processing is intended after you retrieved the values?

Comment: If you build polygons from the areas of interest then zonal statistics from the processing toolbox can perhaps do the rest.

Comment: I would like to see if the values within a range (say 10km or 5 pixels) of the vector lines are statistically different than the sample outside of that buffer. That analysis will likely be done in R, but I am having trouble figuring out how to get the pixel values near the vectors.